# Inheriting function data

Tags: python, function, class, inheritance

I have a question about inheriting data from functions, defined inside another class. I have written an example script to clarify myself. In this script I define a class called `Test`. Here I define `x` and `y` in the `__init__()` function. Thereafter, I make a calculation and return `x,y`. I then create another class called `Inherit_Test` that inherits the `x,y` from `Test`. In this class I define `z` and make a calculation with the inherited values from `Test`. Afterwards, I call the class with Values. The problem arises when I want to access the data stored in Values. The type of this object is "Inherited_Values", while you would expect the type to be `int` and have the value `3*4*43`. I hope I have explained myself well enough, thanks!

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self, x , y ):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
    def Calculation(self):
        self.x = 3*4 #self.x*self.x
        self.y = 43 #self.y*self.y
        return self.x, self.y

class Inherit_Test(Test):
    def __init__(self,z ):
        Test.__init__(self, x = Test.Calculation(self)[0], 
                              y = Test.Calculation(self)[1])
        self.z = z
    def Inherit_Calculation(self):
        self.z = self.x * self.y
        return self.z
    
Value = Inherit_Test(0)
Value.Inherit_Calculation()
```

Comment: I'm unsure exactly what you mean by the `Calculation()` method. Does it expect `self.x` and `self.y` to be initialised, or is it like a setter and is intended to just initialise those attributes?

Comment: For this example x and y do not need to be initialized, so it is more like a setter in this case

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, your question is not very clear defined and it is hard to assume what you exactly wanted to do. I'll try to help you with the following code :

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Calculation()     # instantiation of the self.x and self.y; no init params needed
    def Calculation(self):
        self.x = 3*4 #self.x*self.x
        self.y = 43 #self.y*self.y
        #return self.x, self.y # do you need to return something here ? 

class Inherit_Test(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    # instantiation of the parameters of your super class
        #self.z = z           # do you need this part ? 
    def Inherit_Calculation(self):
        self.z = self.x * self.y
        return self.z
```

Result:

```
Value = Inherit_Test()
print(type(Value.Inherit_Calculation()))
print(Value.x)
print(type(Value.x))
print(Value.y)
print(type(Value.y))
print(Value.z)
print(type(Value.z))

<class 'int'>
12
<class 'int'>
43
<class 'int'>
516
<class 'int'>
```